# Keep css class on Quill clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML

Tags: javascript, typescript, quill

I use the **Quill Text Editor**, and i use the method clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML for paste HTML in the editor, but if i send this :

`let content= '<p class="perso-class">test</p>'; quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(content)`

Editor contents show as: `<p>test</p>`, i want to keep the custom class CSS.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the class with wrapping the content with a div:

```js
let content = '<p class="perso-class">test</p>';
quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(`<div>${content}</div>`);
```

if you don't want to the div around the content, you should add the class name after paste:

```js
quill.root.querySelector('p').classlist.add("perso-class")
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your help, but isn't working